# Как вывести все посты кастомной таксономии?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть кастомная таксономия - "taxonomy" она создана и используется только для кастомного типа поста "home". 
В ней есть такие таксономии(см. скриншот).
Как на странице таксономии Homes вывести все посты которые есть в ней?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы хотите вывести посты стандартном цикле шаблона?

Comment: хоть в каком-то .... я уже гуглил много и не получается ни в каком из циклов вывести....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать реализовать следующим образом. Находим в шаблоне

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Перед этой строкой вставляем

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( array('taxonomy_name'=>'taxonomy') );
query_posts( $args );
```

Можно сказать, это некий костыль,но в тот момент когда я его писал, он меня устраивал. Подробнее https://wp-kama.ru/function/query_posts#parametry-taksonomij

Есть возможность выводить записи по типу поста, в таком случае

```
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'post_type' => 'home' );
```

В принципе весь вывод постов осуществляеться посредством query_posts(), в которую можно передать массу параметров - тип постов, таксономия, сортировка, метки и пр. Подробнее читайте в документации.

P.S. array_merge() делать не обязательно, это добавит к стандартному выводу (напрмер категории и записи) еще Ваш тип/таксономию

Возможно Вам будет полезна следующая информация http://rightblog.ru/1946 https://misha.blog/wordpress/post-types.html https://wpcafe.org/tutorials/rukovodstvo-po-kastomnyim-tipam-zapisey-wordpress/ (смотрите раздел "Создание пользовательского шаблона для пользовательского типа записи")